# What is wrong with my Insert code it gets an unexpected error?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to ask for your help, I have recieving this `error` in my insert.

```
Data truncated for column 'code' at row 1</p>
<p>INSERT INTO `permissions` (`employeeId`, `code`) VALUES ('2', '451</td');
```

I figured out whats wrong and it's the "

Here is my php:

```
if (count($permissionsArray) > 0) {
            // Insert the new permissions to the database.
            $sSQL = "INSERT INTO `permissions` (`employeeId`, `code`) VALUES ";
            foreach ($permissionsArray as $item) {  
                $sSQL.= "('$eid', '$item'),";
            }
            $sSQL = substr($sSQL, 0, strlen($sSQL)-1).";";
            // Execute Query.
            $this->db->query($sSQL);
        }
```

Comment: we can't really tell unless we see where the insert is coming from. show the PHP code

Comment: why is there `</td` in your value ?? can u explain the scenario little bit ?

Comment: that's what i'm figuring out. i dont know where it came from

Comment: best way to this will be removing the </td from variable before you insert it ..

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree with @NeilMartin

Comment: you did not pass any value in sql. how to insert?

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: `http://in2.php.net/strip_tags` Have you tried using strip tag for 
`$items`

Answer (score 0):

You tried to put in data that was longer than what your column definitions allow. Please provide the queries you used for us to see. In addition googling the error message yielded:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,132672,132672#msg-132672
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html
The suggested solution there is to modify the server's "strict mode" setting:

When this manual refers to “strict mode,” it means a mode where at least one of `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is `<td` then it can easily be solved using [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags)

```
  $text = '451</td';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

**OUTPUT** : 451
```

---

**Since you have mentioned `<td` is the problem**

```
I figured out whats wrong and it's the "</td" and that is unacceptable in my database. Does anyone knows how to remove that "</td". - **from question**
```

Here is my php:

```
if (count($permissionsArray) > 0) {
            // Insert the new permissions to the database.
            $sSQL = "INSERT INTO `permissions` (`employeeId`, `code`) VALUES ";
            foreach ($permissionsArray as $item) {  
                            $item = strip_tags($item);//removing html tag
                $sSQL.= "('$eid', '$item'),";
            }
            $sSQL = substr($sSQL, 0, strlen($sSQL)-1).";";
            // Execute Query.
            $this->db->query($sSQL);
        }
```

### **Also check this answer which is similar to your problem**

[data-truncated-for-column-xxxx-at-row-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243998/1877909)

[mysql-data-truncated-for-column-advance-at-row-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19044829/1877909)

[error-data-truncated-for-column-lat-at-row-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19064334/1877909)

[Data truncate for coloumn](http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=5205)

from above links I too would suggest you to check your server mode settings as suggested by kalp in below answer

[data truncated for column XX at row 1](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,132672,132672#msg-132672)

[sql-mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html)